# How to switch to second GPU?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu

I recently found out that my ubuntu laptop had a gtx GPU inside of it, so I wanted to find out what model it was.

when i ran the command: `sudo lshw -C display`
it had this as the output:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:132 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Just in case, I also checked the "about" section in settings, and it said i was using the intel gpu. 
Is there any way I can switch to the intel GPU?

Comment: Hmm... bumblebee looks "very old" to me, maybe it still works though -> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee - have not tried it myself, and just now even uncertain if it really is related. You will probably need to install nvidia drivers to begin with.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to switch *away from* the Intel GPU to the NVidia one, right? Your question asks how to switch *to* the Intel GPU.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo when I wrote that I wanted to switch to the intel gpu